# Can we add two salesforce Org in Web To Lead Form?

Tags: apex, lightning, leads, web2lead

I have a requirement where I need to send the lead generated from the web to lead form to two different salesforce org.

One is to my Org another is to our partner's org who also maintains salesforce, and they want it to send to their org as well.

Is it possible to do, if yes then What should be my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Web-to-Lead does not directly support this. You would need to use additional scripting (either client- or server-side scripting) to submit multiple forms. I recommend using a server-side script to obscure your org Ids, which will reduce spam.